# ChromeDriver for Facebook Login in JAVA?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I've been working on a login with facebook feature on my java program.
I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYPFxrXyK0BwiXNe09hTPjFqYbsWv8gxb).

In this tutorial, it needs to include a chromedriver to a specific project folder in order to open Facebook login page.
Since I am using captain casa framework, I wasn't able to do it. It gives me an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\EnterpriseClientRISC\server\chromedriver.exe
```

But I am not allowed to put the chrome there.

Is there any alternative way to popup facebook login page into another window without using chromedriver?

I saw other tutorial combining javascript, but I am not allowed to do it in my captain casa framework.

Here's my code>

```
try {
            Statusbar.outputSuccessWithPopup("before anything else").setLeftTopReferenceCentered();
            String domain = "https://dev-ecom.partnersbusiness.solutions/";
            String appId = "1830823116979050";

            String authUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+domain+"&scope=user_about_me,ads_management, ads_read email, pages_manage_cta, pages_show_list";


            //TODO SET CHROMEDRIVER HERE
            setNewProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() {
            };

            driver.get(authUrl);
            String accessToken;

            Statusbar.outputSuccessWithPopup("before while").setLeftTopReferenceCentered();

            //Note, wa kaabot after sa login here

            while (true){
                if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("facebook.com")) {
                    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                    accessToken = url.replaceAll(".*#access_token=(.+)&.*", "$1");

                    driver.quit();

                    FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_6);

                    User user = fbClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);

                    setName("User: "+user.getName());

                    Statusbar.outputSuccessWithPopup("Welcome! Mr. "+user.getName()).setLeftTopReferenceCentered();
                }
            }
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Then what browser should I use? I can't implement js SDK so I am using restfb now.  I have no problem on getting the data using chromedriver, but what browser should I use to get the current URL aside of chromedriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm in using chrome driver, it will just help you do the job and avoid cluttered code.
 As you are not able to do same inside c drive put the path to any other drive and put chrome driver exe there.

You should set the chrome driver `exe` path like below.

> setNewProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\some_dir\chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Thanks, error gone but another problem occured.
Please see this. I added different question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686145/popup-facebook-login-page-by-chromedriver